# How to multiply items of two listbox and add them

Tags: vb.net, listbox

There are 2 lisbox. One contains the price of retail product and second contains the quantities of a retail product.

[image]

The user can add as many items as he wants. So the number of items is not limited. I want that when a new item is added**,** code automatically calculates the Total Cash. By multiplying all the items from their quantity list and add them.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest solution is to loop the listbox the contains the price. The index of quantity is equal to the index of price. Right?

```
' this holds the value for the total amount
Dim totalAmount As Integer = 0
' loops the listbox to all items
For a As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
     totalAmount = totalAmount + (CInt(ListBox1.Items(a).ToString) * CInt(ListBox2.Items(a).ToString))
Next
MsgBox(totalAmount)
```

Comment: You repeat ListBox1 twice, I suppose you wanted to refer to ListBox2 after the `*` sign ;-)